# Have any experiments been performed on the magnetic properties of neodymium at high pressure and temperature?

Tags: geomagnetism

As probably everyone here knows, the magnetic property of neodymium disappears at temperatures above ~590°F (310°C) depending on the mix of alloys. Have there ever been any experiments performed to examine how pressure affects the Curie temperature of neodymium alloys? I'm particularly interested in whether or not some neodymium alloys might retain their magnetic properties above their Curie temperature under conditions found, say, within the Earth's outer or inner core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think that pure Nd is ferromagnetic (maybe it's antiferromagnetic?), so your question about the Curie temperature really applies to just certain ferromagnetic alloys of Nd. Not aware of any high-P studies on those ferromagnetic alloys offhand. I was a co-author of a paper that looked at the magnetic properties of the heavy lanthanides (which are ferromagnetic) under pressure, and we found that their Curie temperatures dropped with pressure at a $dT_c/dP$ rate of around -10 to -20 K/GPa (See [High-pressure magnetic susceptibility experiments on the heavy lanthanides Gd, Tb, Dy, Ho, Er, and Tm](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.71.184416)). If Nd alloys have $T_c's$ which drop at similar rates, then I wouldn't expect any magnetism in them at the pressure and temperature of the core-mantle boundary (≈140 GPa and 5000 ˚C).